# How to Tell The Difference Between An Associative and a Regular array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have one regular array:

```
var My_Reg_Array = new Array('some string', 'some other string', 'and another');
```

And one associative array:

```
var My_Associative_Reg_Array = {

'some_key' :'Some string value',
'some_key2' :'Some string value2',
'some_key3' :'Some string value3'

}
```

- **How do I test them with JavaScript to see if which one is associative and which one is regular?**
- **If both are objects... Is then the 'type' of object...  the test we are looking for?**
- **Is there any distinction between these two object types?**

Thank you... Have a nice day :)

Comment: `o.constructor === Array`?

Comment: `{}.toString.call(obj) == '[object Object] or [object Array] or [object Number] or [object RegExp] or [object Date]...'`

Comment: To clarify, giving an array "keys" that are not numbers is no different than giving a random object any property.  So if you set `array[anything]='something'` it will not be subject to any array methods.

Comment: ECMAScript 5 defines `Array.isArray()` for this purpose. It's easily shimmed into older browsers using the technique that @elclanrs pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are objects in javascript, so you need to check for arrays first.

```
if(variable_to_check instanceof Array){
    console.log("I'm an array");
}else if(variable_to_check instanceof Object){
    console.log("I'm just an associative array, but really an Object");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual distinction you're looking for is between an Array and an Object (which you are naming an associative array). But an Array is just a type of Object, so really the test is whether it is an Array at all.

The best check is this:

```
function isArray(x){
    return typeof x === 'object' && {}.toString.call(x) === '[object Array]';
}
```

(in fact, that's practically identical to what jQuery does)

So why not just check the constructor like `x.constructor===Array`? Because it could have been created by another frame, in which case the constructor will not be the same, despite the object being an Array.

Comment: I think there are other places where the constructor check could fail, and it may well work fine with frames sometimes too. I'm not sure about the details there, so I play safe.

Comment: Yes, this is the right way IMO. `{}.toString.call(obj)` is the most reliable way to find out the type of any object.

Comment: Is the 'type' of object...  the test we are looking for then?

Comment: the `type` check just makes sure we don't call `toString` on (say) a number, which would be an error. The important bit is calling `toString` and checking if it says it is an Array.

Comment: @KDawg: Yeah, and AFAIK this is the only bulletproof solution, and it works for _any_ object. `function typeOf(o){ return {}.toString.call(o).match(/\w+/g)[1].toLowerCase() }; typeOf([1,2,3]) //"array"; typeOf(new Date) //"date"...`